# Are there mounted volumes on the iPhone / iPad? How to use these?

Tags: iphone, ipad

NSFileManger has this method:

```
- (NSArray *)mountedVolumeURLsIncludingResourceValuesForKeys:(NSArray *)propertyKeys options:(NSVolumeEnumerationOptions)options
```

the docs say it's for iOS 4.0; That sounds interesting. So I can plug in an USB stick now some time soon? Or can I do so already via the 30-pin connector (if I had a fancy adapter)?

Do you know of some real life use cases for this? I'm playing with low level file stuff around right now, and I'm curious as of what I could do with mounted volumes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the camera connection kit, it's possible that plugged-in cameras count as mounted volumes. That's the only thing I can think of that would cause a mounted volume on an iOS device.

Comment: USB cameras or cameras that use SD cards. You need the [iPad Camera Connection Kit](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC531ZM/A) to do so.